# Filtering an object via a different object via Vue Computed

Tags: object, vue.js

I am trying build a table that is filtered by checkboxes. I have 3 objects:

- selected: What check boxes are currently selected
- sites: What populates the checkboxes. Object Structure: `sites: [{ siteid, name } ...]`
- items: all table items. Object Structure: `items: [{siteid, gradeid, cpl} ..]`

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/J2kBr2Xy
CodePen: https://codepen.io/tomdickson/pen/OqXpay

Hope this provides enough information

Comment: No, it does not. Please show us your code and tell us your problem. Otherwise it is hard to guess what you want to know.

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer Thanks for the feedback mate, I have updated my question and added both a Pastebin and Codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I think this will work.

```
computed: {
    filteredPositions () {
      return this.items.filter(item => this.selected.includes(item.siteid));
    }
  }
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8x3yer54/1/

Just replace computed with this and it works fine.

```
computed: {
        filteredSite() {
            if (!this.selected.length || this.selected.includes(true)) 
                return this.items

             return this.items.filter(item => this.selected.find((item2) => item2.site==item.site))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Patel, unfortunately this hasn't worked but I think it is something I am missing. I have updated my question with a link to the code.